# How can I get the content of this string surrounded by single-quote

Tags: shell

I have a string like this:

```
SOMETHING='abc.abc.abc'
```

How can I extract the content of it ( abc.abc.abc ), inside the single-quotes?

Comment: For what purpose? What about just echo $SOMETHING

Comment: would like extract some variable inside a particular shell script.

Comment: `sed`, `awk`, `expr`, `perl`, `python` - to mention but 5 external (to the shell) commands.  In Bash, there would be ways to do that inside the shell using parameter substitution mechanisms, not invoking an external command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
str="SOMETHING='abc.abc.abc'"
substr=$(echo "$str" | cut -d "'" -f 2)
```

With bash, you could write

```
substr=$(cut -d "'" -f 2 <<< "$str")
```

Or, shell only:

```
IFS="'"
set -- $str
substr=$2
```

Or use an array

```
IFS="'"
fields=($str)
substr=${fields[1]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -F"=\047|\047" '/SOMETHING/{print $(NF-1)}' file
abc.abc.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to already extract it. Example:

```
$ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
SOMETHING='abc.abc.abc'
echo $SOMETHING
$ ./test.sh 
abc.abc.abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged this question as shell. So I guess you're able to use regular expressions in grep. Or perhaps you could do something with javascript regular expressions.

this regex would find it

```
abc\.abc\.abc
```